# Modifying auto complete feature in Sublime text 2

Tags: text, autocomplete, editor, sublimetext2

I write a lot of prose and also transcribe interviews. I have come across the auto complete feature in sublime text 2 and its awesomely fast but the word suggestions are based on the current file.

All I want is to write/use a plugin so that the entire English dictionary can be used while I am typing and not just the current file. The [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) has the priorities as

1. Snippets
2. API-injected completions
3. .sublime-completions files
4. Words in buffer

So can I modify the .sublime-completions files to achieve this. Will there be a lot of delay because of the large number of words? or will the text editor bog down my system performance ?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: The default settings file sets a max file size for auto-complete triggering as ~ 4 million.  I'm presuming they did that for performance reasons. [Here's a resource for the 10K most common words](https://github.com/eurekaoverdrive/google-10000-english), you may want to start there.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this plugin:

https://github.com/Zinggi/DictionaryAutoComplete

It uses the internal English dictionary of ST2 which is located under "/Data/Packages/Language - English/". So you don't have to find a custom dictionary.

Comment: this is perfect! I use it when editing .md markdown files.  to enable  automatic table completion, I just added `"auto_complete_selector": "source, text"` to the user - settings file.